# Why angular js routing is not working for this example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning routing in angular js, please help me with following example. Routing is not working in this example. Do I need to run this on any server?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="myApp">

    <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

    <a href="#/red">Red</a>
    <a href="#/green">Green</a>
    <a href="#/blue">Blue</a>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl : "main.html"
            })
            .when("/red", {
            templateUrl : "red.html"
            })
            .when("/green", {
                templateUrl : "green.html"
            })
            .when("/blue", {
            templateUrl : "blue.html"
            });
        });
    </script>

    <p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

main.html

```
<h2> Hello this is main.html</h2>
```

red.html

```
<h2> Hello this is red.html</h2>
```

green.html

```
<h2> Hello this is green.html</h2>
```

blue.html

```
<h2> Hello this is blue.html</h2>
```

Comment: Where were you trying it ?

Comment: Are u trying this in a web server or browser (as html) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if angular is even loaded. your script tags are outside of your <body> or your not present <head>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # from the href and try once

```
<a href="/">Main</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <p><a href="#/">Main</a>
  </p>

  <a href="#/red">Red</a>
  <a href="#/green">Green</a>
  <a href="#/blue">Blue</a>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          templateUrl: "main.html"
        })
        .when("/red", {
          templateUrl: "red.html"
        })
        .when("/green", {
          templateUrl: "green.html"
        })
        .when("/blue", {
          templateUrl: "blue.html"
        });
    });
  </script>

  <p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Issue is with your angular-route cdn .

Comment: use `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try URL as

```
<p><a href="/">Main</a></p>

<a href="/red">Red</a>
<a href="/green">Green</a>
<a href="/blue">Blue</a>
```

Then only your route prams set with your URL