# angularjs $window.location.href returns page with no css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am linking all CSS and JS files in my index.html and subpages are into templates directory but using $window.location.href it only returns plain html page with no css styles.

On button click page renders fine.
Any idea how to resolve this.

```
.controller('HomepageCtrl', function($scope, $window,$stateParams, $timeout, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion) {
    // Set Header
    $scope.got = function(){
    $window.location.href = '/tempelates/share.html';
    }
    $scope.$parent.hideHeader();

})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using routing in you app?

Answer (score 2):

```
$window.location.href
```

will redirect to out of the app, you must use routing with $location.

Comment: Should I write it as $location.href or $location.path because both doesnt work

Comment: did you configured `$routeProvider` in `app.config()` ?

Comment: @sam, i did an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418480/why-angular-js-routing-is-not-working-for-this-example/40418644#40418644